# (mysql) subquery returns more than 1 row, update set error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE cardkey
SET cardkey.cust_id=(select roomstate.cust_id from roomstate)
where (select cust_id
                from roomstate
                    where roomstate_state=1)
```

I want to update the cust_id in the cardkey table to the cust_id in the roomstate table.

but I got a error.

And...

```
UPDATE cardkey
SET cardkey.cust_id=roomstate.cust_id
where (select cust_id
                from roomstate
                    where roomstate_state=1)
```

also I got rid of the subquery.
still I got a error

roomstate.cust_id is unknown column.

How can I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have more then a cust_id to update uyou could use a  update with join

```
UPDATE cardkey
INNER JOIN roomstate ON cardkey.cust_id = roomstate.cust_id 
    AND roomstate.roomstate_state =1 
SET cardkey.cust_id=roomstate.cust_id
```